# dataset recorded in ASCII format

Tags: dictionary

Sorry i'm new to Spark, scala and hadoop i found many links regarding this weather record data but all of them uses HadoopMapreduce.java to execute but we require to run it in spark to create a DataFrame

I'm trying to create a Dataframe that records the field and perform SQL statement on DataFrame to retrieve max, min and avg temperature for each month

[Explaination for the Line of record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6wuS.png)

This is what i have right now for my Dataframe (i'm using reflection to infer the schema implicitly)

```
scala> case class Weather(station:String, year:Int, month:Int, date:Int, hour:Int, temperature:Double)
scala> val test = input.map(_.split("")).map(p => Weather(p(0),p(1).toInt,p(2).toInt,p(3).toInt,p(4).toInt,p(5).toDouble ))
```

This works fine but only only get a single digit results

```
scala> test.first()
res0: Weather = Weather(0,0,3,5,0,2.0)
```

Problem for me right now it to find a way to spilt the dataset according to its range for each row of records example station is String (4,10) but i can only insert a single Integer value in my map

is there anyway for me to get a range for .map (key => value)

such as `.map(p => Weather(p(4-9),p(10-12))`

or is there any way to split using `regex`?

**EDIT ( I think i explain my question in a wrong way )**

TLDR: A dataset that contains MANY records of data such as seen above have to find a way to spilt it into rows and according to each records find the information that is shown is the picture

[Explaination for the Line of record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6wuS.png)

[a full list of the dataset can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxeev.png)

what i've tried after going through @Yaron's answer

```
 case class Weather(station:String, year:Int, month:Int, date:Int, hour:Int, temperature:Double)
    val splitdata = input.map(_.split(" "))
    scala> val test = splitdata.map(p => Weather(p.substring(4,10),p.substring(15,19).toInt,p.substring(19,21).toInt,p.substring(21,23).toInt,p.substring(23,27).toInt,p(87,92).toDouble ))

       val test = splitdata.map(p => Weather(p.substring(4,10),p.substring(15,19).toInt,p.substring(19,21).toInt,p.substring(21,23).toInt,p.substring(23,27).toInt,p(87,92).toDouble ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to set-up the `substring`,  `case class` and `map`:

1. Input file

I've prepared a test file `/tmp/inp.txt` which holds a sample of 3 input lines.

```
0035029070999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1721
0035029072999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1723
0035029075999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1728
```

I've executed the below commands (the `collect` commands are just for instruction means, and shouldn't be executed in a production-level program)

2. Read the data from local file:

   `scala> val rdd = spark.read.textFile("file:////tmp/inp.txt")
   rdd: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]`
3. Show the content of the rdd

`scala> rdd.collect
    res1: Array[String] = Array(0035029070999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1721, 0035029072999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1723, 0035029075999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1728)`

4. define the `case class`

`scala> case class Weather(station:String, year:Int, month:Int, date:Int, hour:Int, temperature:Double)
    defined class Weather`

5. preform the `map`:

`scala> val rdd2 = rdd.map(p => Weather(p.substring(4,10),p.substring(15,19).toInt,p.substring(19,21).toInt,p.substring(21,23).toInt,p.substring(23,27).toInt,p.substring(87,92).toDouble ))
    rdd2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Weather] = [station: string, year: int ... 4 more fields]`

6. Show the content of the new `rdd2`

`scala> rdd2.collect
    res2: Array[Weather] = Array(Weather(029070,1902,1,4,1300,-94.0), Weather(029072,1902,1,4,1300,-94.0), Weather(029075,1902,1,4,1300,-94.0))`

---

You might want to use `String` `slice` or `substring` methods:

```
scala> val mystr="0035029070999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1721"
mystr: String = 0035029070999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1721

scala> mystr.slice(3,5)
res155: String = 50

scala> mystr.slice(3,8)
res156: String = 50290
```

[More info - slice-scala](https://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-scala)

Comment: any idea how to run it in map()? tried .map(p => Weather(p.substring(4,10) give me error value substring is not a member of Array[String]

Comment: @KevinCiz try removing `.map(_.split(""))`.

Comment: @Shaido it works but i have problem defining the position for temperature since the length of string are different current code looks like this

`val test = input.map(p => Weather(p.substring(4,10),p.substring(15,19).toInt,p.substring(19,21).toInt,p.substring(21,23).toInt,p.substring(23,27).toInt,p(5).toDouble ))`

Comment: Alright got the temperature string position but i face 1 more problem, inside the dataset there's many more data without .map(_.split()) how do i split the data into different rows of records?

Comment: @KevinCiz - If I've answered your question, please accept it. If you have any new question, please post it in a separate question (and in that question post, provide all relevant info - data you are processing, what do you try to do, and what is the expected output)

Comment: @Yaron sorry but that din really resolve my problem, by removing .map(.split()) to run .substring/.slice it creates another problem of not being able to split it into rows

Comment: @KevinCiz - please [edit] your question, provide sample of the input (e.g. a few lines from the input, or link to a file), and sample of the expected output

Comment: @KevinCiz - does the updated answer solve  your question?

Comment: @Yaron what u mentioned i've already did it before when @shaido ask me to remove the .map(_.split("")) as seen from the comments above... but the problem i face is when i have to run more than 1 string `val mystr="0035029070999991902010413004+64333+023450FM-12+000599999V0201601N015919999999N0000001N9-00941+99999098181ADDGF108991999999999999999999MW1721"` can show me an example of using 2 or more strings? i shall attact the 1902 file link [CLICK HERE](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/spring2017/251/module13/1902.txt) i found the exact same file on the internet

Comment: Running only a single string works perfectly fine and ur method is correct thats for sure, but my problem is i have to split my dataset into rows before performing map on each individual rows

Comment: @KevinCiz - I've provided a full working example which uses a file with several input lines

Comment: @KevinCiz - Enjoy! :-)